# ¿Como eliminar el href de un ancla que se encuentra dentro de un string con alguna expresión regular de JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente con un reporte que exporto a PDF. Tomo todo el HTML de una pagina y lo encapsulo en un string para posteriormente generar el PDF con dicho string. El PDF se genera correctamente solo que hay algunas etiquetas que <a> que contienen un href. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna expresión regular que me ayude a eliminar dicho href con su respectivo link.

Cadena:

La liga contiene un parametro GET llamado **adm** cuyo valor cambiara pero siempre sera numerico.

```
<a href="https://www.midominio.com/sistema/index.php?option=adm_cof&item=14&adm=1362" target="_blank">GEC-4789</a>
<a href="https://www.midominio.com/sistema/index.php?option=adm_cof&item=14&adm=1334" target="_blank">GEC-4788</a>
<a href="https://www.midominio.com/sistema/index.php?option=adm_cof&item=14&adm=45" target="_blank">GEC-4543</a>
<a href="https://www.midominio.com/sistema/index.php?option=adm_cof&item=14&adm=2345" target="_blank">GEC-4756</a>
```

Cadena deseada:

```
<a target="_blank">GEC-4789</a>
<a target="_blank">GEC-4788</a>
<a target="_blank">GEC-4543</a>
<a target="_blank">GEC-4756</a>
```

Lo único que he hecho de expresiones es para borrar cosas fijas especificas de una cadena, pero no cuando cierta parte de la cadena cambia diatónicamente.

```
let reg5=RegExp('< href="https://www.midominio.com/sistema/index.php?option=adm_cof&item=14&adm="', 'gi');

    table=table.replace(reg5, '');
```

La expresión que busco es que me remplace el patrón que busco por vació en todo el string que contiene el HTML encapsulado.

Comment: ¿Porqué una expresión regular? Con operaciones sobre cadenas (*String*) sin usar expresiones regulares, lo puedes conseguir. Al final una expresión regular es simplemente una forma más de analizar cadenas. Pero en este caso en particular, me decanto personalmente por los métodos tradicionales: `indexOf()`, `includes()`, `substring()`, `concat()` y compañía. Saludos

Comment: Por otro lado, si lo que estás analizando es un documento `html`, bastará con manipular el elemento o elementos tipo `anchor`, para remover el atributo `href` del mismo. Esa sería otra opción válida. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te digo en mi [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411204/como-eliminar-el-href-de-un-ancla-que-se-encuentra-dentro-de-un-string-con-algu#comment735302_411204), puedes hacerlo sin necesidad de una Expresión Regular. Mi respuesta muestra esta posibilidad.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Asumiendo que las cadenas que contienen los elementos tipo `anchor` están bien formadas, puedes crear tu propia función que elimine el atributo `href` de dichos elementos, usando simples matemáticas y los métodos propios del tipo `String` de [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Por ejemplo, puedes tener una función, que llamaré `getRidOfHref`, la cual recibirá la cadena en cuestión y mediante una serie de cálculos y operaciones sobre la misma se deshará de dicho atributo:

```js
const getRidOfHref = anchorString => {
  if (!anchorString || !anchorString.includes('href="')) {
    return anchorString;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Lo primero que hace mi función es verificar si la cadena está vacía o si la misma no contiene la cadena `href="`, usando [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/includes).

Ahora debemos obtener el índice de `href="`, para ello usaremos el método [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf):

```js
let indexOfHref = anchorString.indexOf('href="');
```

Una vez que conocemos la posición de dicho elemento, podemos ubicar la posición de la doble *comilla* que cierra el atributo `href`. Esto lo hacemos con la subcadena resultante que comienza justo donde termina `href="`.

```js
let indexOfLastDoubleQuotes = anchorString.substring(indexOfHref + 6).indexOf('"');
```

Aquí hemos usado el método [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/substring), para obtener la subcadena adecuada. Como se observa, uso el índice donde comienza `href="` y le sumo exactamente 6 caracteres, que son los que componen la cadena `href="`.

Podemos ver esto en acción:

```js
let cadena = '<a href="https://www.midominio.com/sistema/index.php?option=adm_cof&item=14&adm=1362" target="_blank">GEC-4789</a>';
let indexOfHref = cadena.indexOf('href="');
let subcadena = cadena.substring(indexOfHref + 6);
console.log(subcadena);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Ahora que ya sabemos el índice del cierre de comillas del atributo `href`, podemos *extirpar* esa parte de nuestra cadena. Para ello usaremos una serie de operaciones.

Primero obtenemos la parte inicial de la cadena, la llamaremos `pre` para ser concisos:

```js
let pre = anchorString.substring(0, indexOfHref);
```

Luego obtendremos la parte que viene justo después del cierre del atributo `href`, la llamaremos `post`:

```js
let post = anchorString.substring(indexOfHref + 6).substring(indexOfLastDoubleQuotes + 1);
```

Como se observa, obtengo la cadena desde la posición `indexOfHref + 6`, y de esa parte obtengo todo lo que hay a partir de `indexOfLastDoubleQuotes + 1`.

Teniendo ya la parte inicial (`pre`) y final (`post`), podemos unirlas, y para ello nos apoyamos en el método [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/concat). Además, la parte `post` contiene un caracter de espacio al inicio, y para deshacernos de ese espacio, podemos usar el método [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/Trim). Como esto es el resultado final, podemos devolverlo directamente usando la sentencia `return`.

```js
return pre.concat(post.trim());
```

Con esto ya tienes un método para deshacerte del atributo `href` en una cadena bien formada que represente un elemento `anchor`.

Un ejemplo de esta función:

```js
// diferentes cadena, con atributos href distintos
// la última cadena carece de atributo href
let cadenas = [
  '<a href="https://www.midominio.com/sistema/index.php?option=adm_cof&item=14&adm=1362" target="_blank">GEC-4789</a>',
  '<a href="https://www.midominio.com/sistema/index.php?option=adm_cof&item=14&adm=1334" target="_blank">GEC-4788</a>',
  '<a href="https://www.midominio.com/sistema/index.php?option=adm_cof&item=14&adm=45" target="_blank">GEC-4543</a>',
  '<a href="https://www.midominio.com/sistema/index.php?option=adm_cof&item=14&adm=2345" target="_blank">GEC-4756</a>',
  '<a href="https://otro.dominio.com" target="_blank">GEC-4756</a>',
  '<a target="_blank">GEC-4756</a>'
];

const getRidOfHref = anchorString => {
  if(!anchorString || !anchorString.includes('href="')) {
    return anchorString;
  }
  let indexOfHref = anchorString.indexOf('href="');
  let indexOfLastDoubleQuotes = anchorString.substring(indexOfHref + 6).indexOf('"');
  let pre = anchorString.substring(0, indexOfHref);
  let post = anchorString.substring(indexOfHref + 6).substring(indexOfLastDoubleQuotes + 1);
  return pre.concat(post.trim());
}

cadenas.forEach(cadena => console.log(getRidOfHref(cadena)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.